# Matplotlib boxplot whiskers same width as box

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a boxplot in `matplotlib` where the x-extent of the whisker caps is the same as the x-extent of the box.

Here I generate some simple boxplots:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(size=(100, 3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.boxplot(data)
```

[image]

See that the boxes in the boxplots are wider than the whisker caps. I would like these elements to be the same width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55851692/11021886). However, the linked question asks about a plot generated with `seaborn` rather than directly from `matplotlib`. The solution here is similar, but requires some minor adjustments:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(size=(100, 3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.boxplot(data)

# Loop over the 3 boxes
for i in range(3):
    # Set the limits of the lower whisker to be the same as the box limits
    ax.lines[i*7 + 3].set_xdata(ax.lines[i*7 + 5].get_xdata())
    # Set the limits of the upper whisker to be the same as the box limits
    ax.lines[i*7 + 4].set_xdata(ax.lines[i*7 + 5].get_xdata())
```

[image]

Note that if you pass the argument `showfliers=False` to the call to `plt.boxplot` the resulting axes will only contain 6 lines, rather than 7. Our code should then become:

```
for i in range(3):
    ax.lines[i*6 + 3].set_xdata(ax.lines[i*6 + 5].get_xdata())
    ax.lines[i*6 + 4].set_xdata(ax.lines[i*6 + 5].get_xdata())
```

Passing other arguments to the `plt.boxplot` call may further alter the number of line instances of our axes. Having to alter our code when we change the arguments passed to `plt.boxplot` is a pain.

A better solution would be to keep hold of the data returned by the call to `plt.boxplot` and use this directly:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# Keep hold of the returned
box = ax.boxplot(data)

# Loop over the 3 boxes
for i in range(3):
    # Adjust the lower cap
    box['caps'][2*i].set_xdata(box['boxes'][i].get_xdata()[:2])
    # Adjust the upper cap
    box['caps'][2*i + 1].set_xdata(box['boxes'][i].get_xdata()[:2])
```

This is better, although we're still hardcoding the 3 boxplots (`range(3)`). We can get rid of this as:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# Keep hold of the returned
box = ax.boxplot(data)

# Loop over the n boxes
for i, box_lines in enumerate(box['boxes']):
    # Adjust the lower cap
    box['caps'][2*i].set_xdata(box_lines.get_xdata()[:2])
    # Adjust the upper cap
    box['caps'][2*i + 1].set_xdata(box_lines.get_xdata()[:2])
```

Additionally, the same result can be achieved for horizontal boxplots if we instead alter the ydata:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
box = ax.boxplot(data, vert=False)

# Loop over the n boxes
for i, box_lines in enumerate(box['boxes']):
    # Adjust the lower cap
    box['caps'][2*i].set_ydata(box_lines.get_ydata()[:2])
    # Adjust the upper cap
    box['caps'][2*i + 1].set_ydata(box_lines.get_ydata()[:2])
```

[image]